# How can I get volume id on Windows using Java?

Tags: java, windows, system, system-information

I'm developing a java desktop application to access information, format, change labels and volume id. This app's target are Windows users that will be using mainly Windows XP or Windows 7.

I'm getting basic info using java's File and FileSystemView; and I'm using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to execute external Windows applications to do the other tasks.

I tried to use 'vol' and 'dir' to get the volumeId information but I get the following error:

```
Starting: vol E:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "vol": CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode  encontrar o arquivo especificado
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at app.CommandRunnerWithReturn.run(CommandRunnerWithReturn.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
```

Is there a Java API or Windows program I can use to get volumeid info?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect its a `cmd` command. try `cmd /c vol`

Comment: Maybe `cmd /c vol` might work?

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the fast response!
@PeterLawrey put your answer in a 'stackoverflow-answer' so I can give you credit, since you answered first. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some commands are built in to a shell. To run these commands you need to run the shell to run the command. For CMD you need something like

```
CMD /C VOL
```

for unix shell you need something like

```
sh -c "cd /path ; command > file"
```